# Are indexes on temporary tables deleted when the table is deleted?

Tags: t-sql, indexing, temp-tables

Would the following SQL remove also the index - or does it have to be removed separately?

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl (field int)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON #Tbl (field)

DROP TABLE #Tbl
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes they are. You can search in MSSQL help for CREATE INDEX article it is said there:

> "Indexes can be created on a temporary
>   table. When the table is dropped or
>   the session ends, all indexes and
>   triggers are dropped."

Comment: And obviously. If all the pages are torn out the book, the index is useless and should be torn out too :)

Comment: That's what I thought, but the problem I'm having is that when I recreate the temp table and then attempt to recreate the index (clustered primary key constraint) I'm getting this error: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.##TempFormattedSnapshot' and the index name 'PK_TempSampleID'. The duplicate key value is (422097).

Answer (score 6):

It will be removed automatically, as there is nothing left to index.  Think of it as a child object in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

The drop table will remove the index. Drop Index takes the index name and the table name.

In this case would be DROP INDEX idc ON #tbl

which can be called if you want to drop the index but leave the table.